# Why does this code not increment a counter properly?

Tags: php, session

In my code below, why is it not incrementing the integers by one each time? For example, say I have `1 OF 5` when I submit the form. After submission, it should be `2 OF 5`, but instead, it displays `5 OF 5`. This occurs even if I change the maximum from 5 to 3; it starts at `1 OF 3` and jumps immediately to `3 OF 3`. This is the code to display the `.. OF ..`

```
<h1><?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?></h1>
```

Below is the code which should increment the value by one each time:

```
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
  //Declare my counter for the first time

  $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
  $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
  $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
}
else if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
}

$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

Comment: Are you certain the code isn't being called multiple times, such as might happen if a rewrite rule makes the page load several times?

Comment: I find this a very confusing piece of code. Your code seems to make sense and looks perfectly correct. Why not try to use ``exit($sessionMinus);`` in your code to cancel any other code from being run?

Comment: Are you sure `$_SESSION['sessionNum']` is an integer? If not so, the comparison is irrelevant.

Comment: @Michael I am not certain what is happening, hence why I find it strange on why it doesn't add up by 1 each time. It seems like it starts of with 1 but then when submit form, it goes straight to the last number. Could it be something wrong with `$_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];` as that the last number after the OF is `$_SESSION['sessionNum']` E.g. 1 OF 5 means `$_SESSION['sessionNum']` is 5.

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas $_SESSION['sessionNum'] should be an integer as that if the user enters in the sessionNum textbox 4, then the total number (The number after the OF) should be 4.

Comment: @user1490145 Sure, but generally speaking, HTTP parameters arrive as strings, not something else. I don't know if any kind of implicit conversion is happening, but I think you should check.

Comment: @Luceos If I do an exit then it just leaves me with a blank page with no errors

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas If I echo $_SESSION['sessionNum'] then it does output the number which was entered in it's textbox

Comment: @user1490145 That 's not entirely relevant. If it's a number, then `is_numeric($_SESSION['sessionNum'])` should return `true`.

Comment: @user1490145 Better yet, do a `var_dump($_SESSION['sessionNum'])`. It will dump all info related to the variable.

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas If I do the var dump you told me to do, then if I enter in the number 4 in the textbox, the var dump displays this: `string(1) "4"`. So I am guessing the problem is that it doesn't recognise it as int. HOw can convert it from string to int?

Comment: @user1490145 I will provide an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine. However it is possible that the page is being requested in the background without your knowing. For instance a broken image path etc could be landing on this file hence incrementing your counter. To make sure thats not the case, add a new session array var which records the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or log it to a text file or something.

Comment: Can you provide me an example on how to add $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in a session array, I am a it confused on what you mean.

Comment: The idea is to find out how many requests are landing on that piece of code. So something like `$_SESSION['reqs'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` will store all requests and u can display them at the end with print_r($_SESSION['reqs']). If you see more requests than you are making than it means that something else is requesting the piece of code in the browser background and maybe your code is part of an include file which goes into many pages.

Comment: @user1490145 in simple words figure out a way to see a list of http requests which access that code in ur session.

Comment: Ok, this is strange, if I go on the first page (1 OF 3 for example), the print of the requests shows this :`Array ( [0] => /.../QandATable.php [1] => /.../QandATable.php )` But if I then submit the first page and go onto second page (It should be 2 OF 3 but it is displaying 3 OF 3), then the print shows this: `Array ( [0] => /.../QandATable.php [1] => /.../QandATable.php [2] => /.../QandATable.php [3] => /.../QandATable.php [4] => /.../QandATable.php [5] => /.../QandATable.php )`. Does this mean there are multiple requests happening?

Comment: @user1490145 yup you got it! Check image paths etc or check http requests using firebug in firefox

Comment: What I also find interesting is that I go back to previous page and enter in a new number in the textbox (lets say 4) and submit, then lets say I am on page 1 OF 4, in the print of the requests it adds `/.../QandATable.php [6] => /.../QandATable.php` at end of the array

Comment: @user1490145 that session array wont reset, it will just keep growing, if you want to reset just do that in the first if() block

Comment: I will install firebug, how do I check image paths, why is image paths important? Also do I need to reset $_SESSION(sessionNum) or reset $_SESSION['reqs'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; Would that solve the problem you think?

Comment: The session var i suggested just helps with the debugging, doesn't solve the problem. The image paths are important because you have multiple requests coming through which you aren't aware of, image path are suspects, it could be something else though like ajax calls. So just investigate and figure out where those extra http requests are coming from and you will solve your problem.

Comment: I do have an ajax call as that while the page submits to itself using the form action, I use ajax to submit to another page in the background where it inserts data into the database.

Comment: I have realized the everything works well in fireforx in terms of being able to add up by 1 each time, but it is in google chrome where it start off with 1 and then go straight to the last number after submitting the page. Strange, any ideas why?

Comment: Thats strange, I think open a new question with the relevant code and see what suggestions you get.

Comment: can I quickly provide you a url of a quick example I just made up so you can see for yourself what happens when a user enters in a number in the textbox and then see the number add up each time a user submits the page?

Comment: Strange, when I create a simple example [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text4.php), it works perfectly in chrome and in firefox, and that is including an ajax call. This is very strange. You can test it yourself. But in my full application, it is display 1st number and then when I submit page, goes straight to last number.

Comment: I have to go, I will see your comment on what you think, I will probably  mark your answer when I come back anyway :)

Comment: Yup looks to work well, guess you will have to investigate a little on why it messes up in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Just move `$_SESSION['sessionCount']++;` outside of the if/else statements if you want it to increment every time.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, I don't know if it will work as I cant test it at the moment but I think your issue might be that you cannot do $_SESSION++. Also your'e missing session_start();

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['sessionNum'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
        $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = $_SESSION['sessionCount'] + 1;
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
    $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
    $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
}?>

<h1><?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?></h1>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry this hasn't changed anything. gud effort tho

Comment: I have found out by doing a var dump on $_SESSION(sessionNum) that it outputs this: `string(1) "4"`, could this be a major factor on why it cannot add it up 1 by 1?

Comment: Possibly, I would check the values you are sending over with your post and make sure they are actual numbers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get a string from the `$_POST` http array, which does not automatically get converted to an integer value. In order to do what you want, the above code could be modified thus:

```
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
  //Declare my counter for the first time

  $_SESSION['initial_count'] = intval($_POST['sessionNum']);
  $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = intval($_POST['sessionNum']);
  $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
}
else if ($_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
}

$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

The code also provides a rudimentary input validation, since `intval()` will return `0` if it cannot parse the number.

Comment: I think the problem is with http request in one on the answers as I have found out I am getting multiple requests

Comment: Since you 're reporting `var_dump` returns a string type, this could be a problem too.

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas I don't really think its the issue because the increment is happening and is being capped correctly, if the string comparison was the issue the elseif wouldn't fire.

Comment: I will definetly change it to intval so it stays as a int the whole time

Comment: @user1490145 its one of the bad things about PHP, it lets you get lazy, you should def go with explicitly converting it to the right type whenever you can.