# jquery function I believe is messing up php function

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display the correct page number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526949/how-to-display-the-correct-page-number)

I have a piece of code below where it determines which assessment the user is in and the assessment number the user is currently on:

```
<h1>CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?></h1>
```

So on the browser this could read for example:

```
CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT 1 OF 4
```

Now below I have a submit button:

```
<input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
```

Now if the user clicks on the button, it will show a confirmation box and if the user clicks OK, for the confirmation, then it will submit the page and what is suppose to happen is that it adds a number to the assessment to indicate that the user is on the next assessment.

SO FOR EXAMPLE:

If it says this on the page:

```
CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT 1 OF 4
```

If the user submits the page and confirms, then it should now say this:

```
CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT 2 OF 4
```

This is because the user is on the next assessment now.

But the problem is that it is not adding the number at all when the user submits the page. It just stays at '1' and doesn't add up. So instead of doing the above it is doing the below:

If it says this on the page:

```
CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT 1 OF 4
```

If the user submits the page and confirms, then it still says:

```
CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT 1 OF 4
```

This is obviously incorrect.

So my question is that does anyone know why it is not adding up the number? I know that the php is not the problem because I tested my code and what I have found is that if there is no jquery `validation()` function, then the code works fine and it adds the number up from 1 onwards.

But if I include the jquery `validation()` function which is needed, then it doesn't add the number at all and just stays at 1.

Can anybody help and fix this problem?

You can test the application yourself [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text4.php), just follow steps below:

1. When you open link type in number 5 in the textbox and submit page
2. When you have navigated to next page you see on top it states `CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT 1 OF 5`. Now scroll to bottom of page and click "Submit Details" button and confirm the confirmation box.
3. You will see that the heading still states `CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT 1 OF 5` and not `CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT 2 OF 5`.

Below is relevant code so you know what the code is:

```
<?php

session_start();


if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
            //Declare my counter for the first time

            $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = intval($_POST['sessionNum']);
            $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;

    }

elseif (isset($_POST['submitDetails']) && $_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
}


$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];

if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = 'create_session2.php'; 

}elseif($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">


function validation() {

    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    var alertValidation = "";
    // Note, this is just so it's declared...
    $("tr.optionAndAnswer").each(function() {


        _qid = $("td.qid",this).text();
        _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";

        $(".textAreaQuestion",this).each(function() {



            if (!this.value || this.value.length < 5) {
                alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered a valid Question\n";
            }

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }
        });

               if(alertValidation != ""){
            return false;
        }

        });


    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}




             function showConfirm(){

         var confirmMsg=confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards Questions, Options and Answers for your Session." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" );

         if (confirmMsg==true)
         {
         submitform();   
     }
}

         function submitform()
{
    var fieldvalue = $("#QandA").val();
    $.post("insertQuestion.php", $("#QandA").serialize() ,function(data){
        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
        QandAO.submit();
    });  
    alert("Your Details for this Session has been submitted"); 
}




</script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post">

<h1>CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?></h1>

<p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;" /></p>

</form>

         <script type="text/javascript">

function myClickHandler(){
     if(validation()){
                showConfirm();
     }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a submit this code is run:

```
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])){
  ...
  $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
}

$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

and the this is displayed in the browser:

```
<h1>
  CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS: ASSESSMENT 
  <?php $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?>
</h1>
```

The result of $sessionMinus is always 1 !!

Comment: But shouldn't this code take affect as well: `elseif (isset($_POST['submitDetails']) && $_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;`? This will add it by 1

Comment: Do a var_dump($_SESSION) before $sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];

Comment: The var_dump outputs this: `array(3) { ["sessionCount"]=> int(1) ["initial_count"]=> string(1) "5" ["sessionNum"]=> int(5) }` What does this mean? The output is for both before and after the submit of the page

Comment: It means that my answer is right! ["sessionCount"]=> int(1)

Comment: But what can be done to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is a valid statement:

`$_SESSION['sessionCount']++;`

I think you need to set it like so:

`$_SESSION['sessionCount'] = $_SESSION['sessionCount'] + 1;`

Comment: Also, I'm not completely sure on this, but you may need to cast `$_SESSION['sessionCount']` to an integer/number/whatever.

Comment: $_SESSION['sessionCount']++; is perfectly OK!